# MS SQL Selecting Specific dates with condition

Tags: sql-server

```
Ins No  AimSeqNumber    LearnRefNumber  LearnStartDate  DateEmpStatApp  EmpId
1000214  1                  10v1         2017-06-30     2016-08-30  900271388
1000214  1                  10v1         2017-06-30     2016-07-30  900271388
1000214  1                  10v1         2017-06-30     2014-07-30  900871388
1000214  1                  10v1         2017-06-30     2015-07-30  905271388
```

Hi I have a table like this. I want to get the empID where Latest DateEmpStatApp  on or before the LearnStartDate

I am not sure how to approach this. My initial logic was to use date-part function and find the difference in days. Then use min function to get the selected row. However I will still get more than one row. As I only want the empid for latest DateEmpStatApp  date that corresponds to the learnstartdate

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP (1) EmpId 
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateEmpStatApp < LearnStartDate
ORDER BY DateEmpStatApp DESC
```

Simply limit to the first row that meets your conditions

- "DateEmpStatApp on or before the LearnStartDate"
- "Latest DateEmpStatApp"

Edit, after comment

```
SELECT EmpId, LatestDateEmpStatApp = MAX(DateEmpStatApp)
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateEmpStatApp < LearnStartDate
GROUP BY EmpId
```

Comment: If I have thousands of different learnrefnumber how will it show the rows for the others as I am limiting it to only one?

Comment: @AshikurRahman "learnrefnumber" is not in your sample table, and you only have one EmpId. in the sample data.